# How do I create a case-insensitive lexer

Tags: scala, lexer, parser-combinators

I'm trying to create a SQL lexer (well, a full parser but you have to start somewhere) and I'm  not sure how to proceed. I want to write something like this:

```
def nextToken(input: List[Char]) = input match {
  case 'S'::'E'::'L'::'E'::'C'::'T'::tail => (SELECT, tail)
  case _ => ??? // etc.
}
```

But SQL is case insensitive. I could uppercase all the characters in input, but that would also uppercase strings. What I really need is a way to do case insensitive comparisons, and then be left with the correct `tail` (remainder `List[Char]` after matching a token). Is there a way to do this easily in Scala 2.10.x?

Comment: Can you just uppercase the whole input string first, and then all your code can just use uppercase chars?

Comment: No, then the strings would be upper case also. I don't want to corrupt the input.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I need this to be an efficient parser, so @dhg's answer doesn't work for me. This is the answer I settled on. It uses a variation of a case insensitive [Trie](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trie) but where

1. Shortest match wins
2. We don't consume the whole search input. We only consume up to a match and no more.

Here's the Trie:

```
    case class CaseInsensitiveTrie[T](children: List[Node[T]] = Nil) {
        def add(key: List[Char], value: T): CaseInsensitiveTrie[T] = {
            def loop(key: List[Char], nodes: List[Node[T]]): List[Node[T]] = key match {
                case c::Nil =>
                    nodes.find(_.key == c) match {
                        case Some(node) => nodes // No updating values
                        case None => Node(c, Some(value), Nil) :: nodes
                    }
                case c::tail =>
                    nodes.find(_.key == c) match {
                        case Some(node) =>
                            val children = loop(tail, node.children)
                            val newNode = Node(c, None, children)
                            newNode :: nodes.filterNot(_.key == c)
                        case None =>
                            val children = loop(tail, Nil)
                            val newNode = Node(c, None, children)
                            newNode :: nodes
                    }

                case Nil => ??? // Programmer error
            }

            CaseInsensitiveTrie(loop(key, children))
        }

        def find(input: List[Char]): Option[(T, List[Char])] = {
            def loop(input: List[Char], nodes: List[Node[T]]): Option[(T, List[Char])] = input match {
                case c::Nil =>
                    nodes.find(_.key.toUpper == c.toUpper).flatMap(_.value.map(_ -> Nil))
                case c::tail =>
                    nodes.find(_.key.toUpper == c.toUpper).flatMap {
                        case node if node.value.isDefined =>
                            node.value.map(_ -> tail)
                        case node =>
                            loop(tail, node.children)
                    }
            }

            loop(input, children)
        }
    }

    object CaseInsensitiveTrie {
        case class Node[T](key: Char, value: Option[T], children: List[CaseInsensitiveTrie.Node[T]])
    }
```

There's only 2 functions - `find` and `add`. Fill the trie with only the case-insensitive keywords, then we create this unapply function:

```
val trie = CaseInsensitiveTrie[Token]()
  .add("SELECT".toList, SELECT)
  .add("FROM".toList, FROM)
  .add("WHERE".toList, WHERE)
  .add("AS".toList, AS)

object Keyword {
  def unapply(input: List[Char]): Option[(Token, List[Char])] = {
    trie.find(input)
  }
}
```

So that in the match we can test for a match and simultaneously pull the match and remainder of the input:

```
  input match {
    case '*'::tail         => (STAR, Scan(tail, location + 1).trim)
    case '('::tail         => (LPAREN, Scan(tail, location + 1).trim)
    case ')'::tail         => (RPAREN, Scan(tail, location + 1).trim)
    case '.'::tail         => (DOT, Scan(tail, location + 1).trim)
    case ','::tail         => (COMMA, Scan(tail, location + 1).trim)
    case '='::tail         => (EQ, Scan(tail, location + 1).trim)
    case '<'::'>'::tail    => (NE, Scan(tail, location + 2).trim)
    case '>'::tail         => (GT, Scan(tail, location + 1).trim)
    case '>'::'='::tail    => (GE, Scan(tail, location + 2).trim)
    case '<'::tail         => (LT, Scan(tail, location + 1).trim)
    case '>'::'='::tail    => (LE, Scan(tail, location + 2).trim)
    case Keyword(kw, tail) if tail.headOption.fold(true)(_.isWhitespace) =>
      (kw, Scan(tail, location + kwLength(kw)).trim)
  }
```

This isn't the fastest Trie implementation available, but it works for my needs. If performance becomes an issue at all, I can make it a compressed trie

Answer (score 0):

It seems like a regular expression might solve this nicely if the input is left as a String.

```
val SelectRe = """(?i)SELECT(.*)""".r            // the (?i) makes it case-insensitive

def nextToken(input: String) = input match {
  case SelectRe(tail) => (SELECT, tail)
  case _ => ??? // etc.
}
```

Comment: Is there a way to do this *without* wasting a ton of memory? I used `List[Char]` for the input because separating the head from the tail is constant time with zero extra memory usage.